# plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I'm using the following code that allows to share an image with a text:

```
- (IBAction)sharePressed:(id)sender {
    UIImage *postingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Lorem ipsum", postingImage] applicationActivities:nil;
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Posting the image to Facebook works fine and it appears on my FB wall, however in my console I get the following message:

`plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated`

I've tested it on a couple of devices, as far as I could see it only happens on my iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1 installed.

Anyone knows what that message means and how to prevent it from showing?

Comment: Hey man, also get the same message when posting a message with a screenshot. The post works fine, they appear on fb. using Unity iOS Pro. The message appears in Xcode, for anyone that has never heard of unity. Please let us know if you find out why and i will do the same. I'm uploading my game anyway and will let you know if it gets rejected or not.

Comment: How did it go Luke? Get through?

Comment: happens on iPhone 5S (8.1) too

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that log

Comment: Happened with me too. Posts appear just fine on Twitter and FB though I get the messages on console like plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated and LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called.

Comment: I have got same error "plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated" when sharing FB on iOS 8.2 simulator. Any update on this ?

Answer (score 15):

Here is the correct answer [ios plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post do not show provided text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875123/ios-plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-do-not-show-provided-text). It's a bummer.

> I'm afraid to tell you, you cannot post text to Facebook programatically. It's a new Facebook prohibition that forbids "pre-filled" Facebook sharing. That is why newer versions of iOS do not show your text, even tough it's correctly provided (and works on Twitter and in other sharing options).
>
> For more info please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrible error message by Apple. Go to settings and check your facebook/twitter accounts. You will notice they have no password set (perhaps this happens after updating to 8.1). Just update the account info and the message will be gone and your post/tweet will work.

Comment: Actually, I get the error message when the password is set, and the Facebook post works. The error message appears spurious.

Comment: It's not spurious, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this is related to the fact that the Facebook app replaces the iOS system level Facebook share extension with a custom one. Case is triggered as follows:

1. Load an app and share to Facebook (Note: Facebook app is currently
   installed)
2. Exit app
3. Delete the Facebook app from device
4. Open app again (still active in memory) and share to Facebook ...
   fail! The app is looking for a share extension that was
   uninstalled along with the Facebook app

Kill and restart the app, share to Facebook. Voila! The app has loaded the default iOS Facebook share extension and it works again.

Head scratcher as to why Apple let Facebook take this approach as opposed to either forcing them to replace the default Facebook share extension or just not allowing them to inject their own, only if their app is installed.

Comment: You are the man! I was getting that nasty error and thanks to your post I realized that it was because of the Facebook app. I think my problem was because not long time ago I changed my user name on Facebook, so the app was working but there was some internal conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It also happen when u try to set an `URL` using `addURL:` method for `SLServiceTypeTwitter` in your `SLComposeViewController`. Deleting it fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has updated their policy. It doesn't work with this anymore. you need to integrate Facebook sdk to do so. here is the relevant references for those who want to share image or post from your app to Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios#sharedialog

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was using **activity controller** and **SLComposeViewController**, and in both cases got the same error, even if i don't set any text/url etc for fb programatically. So according to me, in my case, it was not the issue of new facebook policy as mentioned in comment above.

To avoid any inconvenience in future, i fixed it by using **facebook share SDK** (not using SLComposeViewController or activityViewController now). FBSdk is integrated in my iOS project and the code, i used for sharing purpose is as:

```
@IBAction func shareOnFaceBook(sender: AnyObject) {

    var content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = urlToShare()      //method returning the url
    content.contentDescription = textToShare()    //method returning text(string) to share

    var dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Automatic
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.delegate = self
    dialog.fromViewController = self
    dialog.show()
}
```

It'll open fb application (if installed), Otherwise will open Safari (fb web application).Hope that it'll help you

Best,

Comment: In some answers i  found that "check settings in iPad. May be you have not entered valid account for facebook etc." But it also didn't help me as in my case all settings were appropriate