# Xcode Debug Area says Facebook/Twitter posts invalidated

Tags: ios, facebook, button, twitter, share

I created 2 separate share buttons, one for Facebook the other for twitter in my iOS game app.

The debug area states:

plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated

why does it say invalidated when the share button works and the posts get sent to Facebook?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me (only plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated in my case). However the post is tweeted without problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332273/plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated)

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is quite old but for other users, the issue and it's solution has been shared on this stackOverflow link: 
[plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332273/plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated/31439243#31439243)

Hope that it'll help. Best,