# ios plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post do not show provided text

Tags: ios, xcode, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app I'm using the following code that allows to share an image with a text:

```
- (IBAction)sharePressed:(id)sender {
    UIImage *postingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Lorem ipsum", postingImage] applicationActivities:nil;
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And when posting I can see image, but can't see text. Also text doesn't appear in FB.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid to tell you, you cannot post text to Facebook programatically. It's a new Facebook prohibition that forbids "pre-filled" Facebook sharing. That is why newer versions of iOS do not show your text, even tough it's correctly provided (and works on Twitter and in other sharing options).

For more info please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill)

Comment: But even if i type my own text in the dialog, same error occurs. How would the user know that for sharing she must not type anything? Please suggest me any alternatives to this problem :)

Comment: The users can type whatever they want. The App CANNOT pre-type the comment field. Even if you do, it will appear empty. There is no work around this, and even if you found one, it is against Facebook usage policy.

Comment: Thanks. Verified this: user can type his own text but programmer can't set preset text.

Comment: Same for posting via `FBSDKShareDialog`, either using Facebook App or iOS Sharing dialog. This is annoying. I want to pre-fill texts

Comment: Me too, but the owners of Facebook don't want us to. Nothing for us to do here. And I think it could be better for the user anyway.

Comment: The work around I know is to save the text in the UIPasteboard and show an alert or any notification to the user that he has to paste it himself

Answer (score 3):

I first saw this when Facebook updated their app on April 24th. Plain text sharing to Facebook isn't working as long as the Facebook app is installed. After you delete it, it's available again.

If you try to share a URL or an image together with the plain text, you will see Facebook as an option but the text field will be blank. The image or URL will attach without a problem.

I posted a sample project that reproduces this problem on github:

https://github.com/djr/UIActivityViewController-Facebook

This is not an answer, but it's pretty clear that the problem is caused by the Facebook app.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have sent this bug to FB :)

Comment: It is NOT a bug, is due to a new policy restriction. Please refer to my answer.