# ios plugin com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension invalidated

Tags: ios, gmail, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share **Text** in **Gmail** with **UIActivityViewController**  but i am getting this message in log.

> plugin com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension invalidated.

Due to this i am not getting mail in my Gmail inbox.

I have also tried to add entry of **APPTransportSecurity** in .plist

[image]

I have also followed all the steps which said in [plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332273/plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated) question.

But still i am getting message in my log and not able to get mail in Gmail inbox.

Here is my code for  **UIActivityViewController** implementation.

```
NSString *P_Name =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product Name :- %@ \n Offers :- %@",[[arryDetail objectAtIndex:selectedindex] objectForKey:@"productname"],[[arryDetail objectAtIndex:selectedindex] objectForKey:@"offers"]];


    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[P_Name];




    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                    UIActivityTypeMail,
                                    UIActivityTypePrint,
                                    UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                    UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Note:-** I am successfully able to send message in whatsapp with this warning.

> plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275448/gmail-extension-crashes-when-sending-images-using-uiactivityviewcontroller