# Gmail Extension crashes when sending images using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use UIActivityViewController to share multiple images but when I choose a Gmail in the list, it opens it, then I see my attached files and then Gmail extension crashes. Next time it even doesn't open when I choose it.

But everything works fine with Mail app or other apps in the list in UIActivityViewController.

```
NSArray *scans = self.document.scans;
NSMutableArray *imagesData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[scans count]];

    for (DScan *scan in scans) {
         UIImage *image = [scan fullImageWithError:nil];
         [imagesData addObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)];
    }

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:imagesData applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please help my understand what is wrong in the code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In logs I see the following: plugin com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension interrupted
plugin com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension invalidated