# SLComposeViewController SLServiceTypeFacebook doesn't work in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, facebook

I have following code:

```
  SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
  SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    else
      NSLog(@"Done");

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
  };
  controller.completionHandler = myBlock;
  [controller setInitialText:@"blah blah"];

  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

I have tried across > iOS versions 8.x, however, i found only on iOS 9.1, the `Post` button is greyed and text field is empty, while in newer iOS version 9.3.1 isn't.

Anyone has idea? i suspect because of this:

> plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

which lead me to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332273/plugin-com-apple-share-facebook-post-invalidated) and found that Facebook's policy doesn't allow pre-filled text, but why in iOS 9.3.1 works.

**Update**:
Post button is enabled again after I type some text on the text field.

Comment: Re your update, can you no longer reproduce the issue in your question?

Comment: Well actually, I wonder why `initialText` only doesn't work for iOS 9.1

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
{
    let twitterComposeVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    twitterComposeVC.setInitialText(messagge)
    twitterComposeVC.addURL(NSURL.init(string: url))

    fromController.presentViewController(twitterComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    print("No twitter account is configured in settings.");
}
```